# Downgrading to a previous version of an iphone app

Tags: iphone, version, app-store-connect

I have an app on appstore.

I uploaded a new version and it was published. But, just after that I realized an important bug in my app. Since the approvement process takes a long time, I want to downgrade to the previous version until the fixed version is approved by Apple.

Are there any way for that?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

The only way to downgrade is to resubmit the previous version with a new version number, or a new fixed version, and wait until it is approved.  If you put a note in the Demo Account section saying this is a rollback or a critical bug fix, there are reports that Apple may perhaps expedite the review.  If the bug is bad enough to create very unhappy customers, you can warn customers not to download it in your update notes, and/or you can set the availability date of the current broken version into the future, until your fix is accepted.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately not, Apple doesn't provide a means of rolling back to previous versions.  If you have the source code, you could always just increment the version number and upload the old version again.

Answer (score 1):

like the other answers have said - unfortunately, Apple does not provide a way to rollback once you've released the app.

The way many major apps deal with this is by instrumenting their app ahead of time with feature flags (https://martinfowler.com/articles/feature-toggles.html): ways to enable/disable features and codepaths from the server.

Granted that implementing feature flags requires foresight and planning (it's unlikely you'll capture every codepath). Fwiw, I started my current company (https://screenplay.dev) out of this frustration; you can read much more on this approach here: [itunesconnect App - Revert to previous version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21899714/itunesconnect-app-revert-to-previous-version/63852413#63852413) :)